# How can one column in the result of a MySQL query be removed?

Tags: mysql, sql

Example:

```
SELECT `film_id`,COUNT(film_id) AS COUNT FROM films_genres AS FilmsGenre   
WHERE genre_id In (4)  
GROUP BY film_id,COUNT 
HAVING COUNT = 1
```

return:

```
film_id |  COUNT
7            1   
6            1
```

But I want it to return:

```
film_id
  7
  6
```

How do I return only 1 colomn?

Comment: Answered by pranay and madhiva

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do it, just move your "`COUNT(film_id)`". Your `HAVING` clause will do the work for you.

```
SELECT `film_id` FROM films_genres AS FilmsGenre
WHERE genre_id In (4)
GROUP BY anime_id,film_id
HAVING COUNT(film_id) = 1
```

Comment: i think this will make no difference because goal is to remove count field form the select and have to select rows where film_id==1

Answer (score 1):

This isn't phrased as a CakePHP question,although it's tagged as such.

However, in CakePHP:

`$this->FilmGenre->find('list',array('fields'=>array('film_id','film_id','anime_id')));`

Answer (score 1):

or make use of derived table

```
SELECT film_id from
(
SELECT `film_id`,COUNT(film_id) AS COUNT FROM films_genres AS FilmsGenre    
WHERE genre_id In (4)   
GROUP BY anime_id,COUNT  
HAVING COUNT = 1  
) as t
```